# ideals of ring $A $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $A=\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle X^n\rangle$. Show that $A$ admits $n-1$ proper ideals.

I know that:

$$ 
A = \{a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} : a_i \in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
 and 
$$I_i=\langle x^i\rangle $$ for $i=1,\dots,n-1$
 are proper ideals of $A $. But how do I show that she is are unique?

Comment: Are you sure it is $\mathbb R$ and not $\mathbb R[X]$?

Comment: @N.S. see the correction

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of a Euclidean domain (and that $\mathbb R[X]$ is such a domain)?  It helps Readers to gauge your level of studies if you share where the problem was encountered.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1** If $I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle X^n\rangle $ then there exists an ideal $J$ in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $\langle X^n\rangle  \subseteq J$ such that $I=J/ \langle X^n\rangle $.

**Hint 2** $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is a PID.

**Hint 3:** For polynomials $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ you have $\langle P \rangle  \subseteq \langle Q\rangle $ if and only if $Q$ divides $P$.

Comment: But I can not show that if we take a polynomial $ P$ of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ such that there exists an $i \in\{ 1 ,..., n-1\} $ such that: $⟨P⟩/⟨X^n⟩=⟨x^i⟩ $

Comment: @Khan What does it mean that $<X^n> \subseteq <P>$?

Comment: no, I want to say that to show that the only ideals of $A$ are the $I_i$ we have to show that for every $P\in\mathbb {R}[X]  $ such that there exists an $i\in \{1,...,n−1\} $ such that: $⟨P⟩/⟨X^n⟩=I_i$ or  $⟨P⟩/⟨X^n⟩=0$ or $⟨P⟩/⟨X^n⟩=A $

Comment: @N.S. why is it that if $I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle X^n\rangle,$ there exists an ideal $J$ in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $\langle X^n \rangle \subseteq J$ and $I=J /\langle X^n\rangle$?

Comment: @SimonFraser This is a standard result about factor rings. If you don;t know it, just define $J:= \{ f \in \mathbb R[X] : f+ <X^n> \in I \}$. Show that this is an ideal, it contains $<X^n>$ and $J/<X^n> =I$.

Answer (score 2):

An ideal of $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^n)$ corresponds to an ideal $I=(P)$ of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $(X^n)\subseteq I$ where $P$ is a polynomial ($I$ is principal because $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is a PID). Therefore there is polynomial $Q$ such that $X^n=PQ$. Writing $P=\sum a_iX^i$ and $Q=\sum b_jX^j$ the equation $X^n=PQ$ says that the term of degree $0$ of the product $PQ$ is zero, that is, $a_0b_0=0$. Thus $a_0=b_0=0$. There are $i,j$ such that $a_i\neq0, b_j\neq0$ and $i+j=n$. By induction one can check that $a_l=0$ for $l<i$ and $a_i=1$. With a similar argument one can verify that $a_p=b_q=0$, where $p$ and $q$ are the degrees of the $P$ and $Q$ respectively, and that $a_l=0$ for $l>i$. This argument implies that $P=X^i$.